# How to change HTML of "Shipping & Handling" line on cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In the shopping cart page of my magento store, there is a line item for Shipping & Handling. I am trying to change the HTML output of this line. I have figured out how to change the actual text "Shipping & Handling - Method" , but I would like to change the actual HTML output. I looked through all of my theme files and could not figure out where to access this. I simply need to add a CSS class for that line so I can style it. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried turning on block/template hints?

Comment: Yes, it points to the totals.phtml file in base/default. But in that file, it simply displays this function: "<?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>" .. Do you know how I might access the HTML generated by this function? It is generating <td> tags, and I need to add a CSS class to one of them.

Comment: No that shows for everyone so not a good idea to turn it on for a live site. Also not a good idea to work on a live site directly...but if you must, I assume you have looked under in the `checkout` template files directory?  It's impossible to say exactly which template it will be in without looking at your install as by default there is nothing reading Shipping & Handling on the cart page, however if it's just a modified Estimate Shipping and Tax block you might want to look in the `checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` template location for your relevant theme.

Comment: You can apply IP condition to display hint.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution to take if you are not a developer is to update the translation of that line of text in your translation file `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv` if it isn't already in there just add a line at the end. The first part is what the text currently is and the second is what you want it to read.

tread lightly, it effects that line of text anywhere on your site.

If you just need to style some text add the html of that section and I can help you with a selector.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for is app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php you will

```
 $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling');
```

Under fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) function and around 20th line. There you can change but editing magento core file is not recommended. So you have two solutions

1. Copy Shipping.php file in to local code pool and edit there
2. This is the best way create your own module for override Shipping.php file by extending Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping class you can find a tutorial of creating module at steve perrys' [blog](http://www.steveperrycreative.com/how-to-change-the-magento-shipping-handling-output/)